Как получить список папок с файлами в чистом js без использования node.js?
Может есть какая-то уловка. Имел виду нечто вроде этого.
function loadScript(url) {
    return new Promise((r, j) => {
        const s = document.createElement('script');
        s.src = url;
        s.onload = () => r(Script ${url} loaded);
        s.onerror = () => j(new Error(Failed to load script ${url}));
        document.body.appendChild(s);
    });
}

loadScript('src/file/_js/math.js')
    .then(() => console.log(add(1, 2)))
    .catch(console.error);

Тут по сути выдает ошибку в случае некоректного кода + отсутствия файла. С помощью которого можно по крайней мере получить список всех js файлов, только не оптимизированным способом конечно, имено подбором названий и это не оптимизированный способ.

В HTTP не существует ни понятия «папка», ни даже понятия «файл», в связи с чем вопрос не имеет смысла
